# How to resize carousel control prev/next buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to resizse the carousel prev/next buttons?  I have tried to resize based on height and width and they do resizes but they don't scale. Is there a carousel-control-small type of class
like that of a btn (small-btn, etc,...)

Here is what I have tried:

```
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next" style=" height: 30px; width:30px">&rsaquo;</a>
```

Comment: No there's no special class for that, you will need to play around with the css until you get them looking the way you want. `height` and `width` will scale the circle, for the arrow you need to adjust `font-size` and probably `line-height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per @koala_dev:

No there's no special class for that, you will need to play around with the css until you get them looking the way you want. height and width will scale the circle, for the arrow you need to adjust font-size and probably line-height

Answer (score 2):

```
if you are making use of the default boostrap carousel the next and previous icon
 is located in this span below
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon fontIcon" aria-hidden="true"></span>


<span class="carousel-control-next-icon fontIcon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
create a css class like this
.fontIcon{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color:black;
border-radius: 15px;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can resize prev/next icons like this

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon 
{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
    
.carousel-control-next-icon
{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I did was to modify the CSS directly. You have to modify the classes

`a.left.carousel-control` and `a.right.carousel-control`

to change the WIDTH. And for the HEIGHT you have to modify the carousel itself.